# A good method to get money from a model

Tags: salary

I have read mathematics and statistics and now a person asked me to optimize a particular problem. I have found solution such that we can maximize particular expressions by some method and particular expression by another method and so on. But I haven't found a general method to find universal optimal solution, and I think it is impossible to find it but I have not a proof of it.

But now the customer will pay salary only if he gets the universal optimal solution to the problem. What would be the best way to get the salary? Mail to him: "Okay, I have a particular solution written in PDF and you will get it after you pay the salary on my IBAN"?

I'm unemployed at the moment.

Comment: You _have found solution such that we can maximize particular expressions by some method_. I suggest you to use that to maximize your salary and then mail to the customer for a job.

Comment: I agree with @scaahu. As soon as you actually find a job, you're golden because you'll be able to use that solution to maximize your salary. Also, have you considered selling that solution on eBay to other people who have a similar problem? That might be another way that you could maximize your salary. In any event, good luck! I wish you all of the best! And welcome to TWP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This person is asking you to work for no pay. This is a common scam on the internet. One of the telltale signs of the scam is the customer's demand for a "universal optimal solution."

With respect, stop expecting to be paid by this rascal for your time spent on this problem.

If you make a business of consulting, then establish upfront with customers that you will be paid an hourly rate for your work. If you understand a customer's problem very well, you can choose to quote a fixed flat rate for solving it. But in that case you need a contract.